# Efficient way to load csv file in spark/scala

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, databricks

I am trying to load a csv file in scala from spark. I see that we can do using the below two different syntaxes:

```
  sqlContext.read.format("csv").options(option).load(path)
  sqlContext.read.options(option).csv(path)
```

What is the difference between these two and which gives the better performance?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**There's no difference.**

So why do both exist?

- The `.format(fmt).load(path)` method is a flexible, *pluggable* API that allows adding more formats without having to re-compile spark - you can register aliases for custom Data Source implementations and have Spark use them; "csv" [used to be](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv) such a custom implementation (outside of the packaged Spark binaries), but it is now part of the project
- There are shorthand methods for "built-in" data sources (like `csv`, `parquet`, `json`...) which make the code a bit simpler (and verified at compile time)

Eventually, they both create a CSV Data Source and use it to load the data.

Bottom line, for any supported format, you should opt for the "shorthand" method, e.g. `csv(path)`.